# Laravel search for the close results

Tags: laravel

My app has an option to battle another player.
In order to match a player with another, I created a database field named `score` in my `users` table.

My goal is to match user with a another random user who is already `SEARCHING` for a battle. Both of the users has to be on +-100 score difference.

For example, user with score of 100 can battle players with score of 0-200.

I'm trying to search for all of the available options, but couldn't get how to do this.

Currently, I just output the first one in `SEARCHING` mode.

```
$pvp = PvpBattle::where('mode','=','SEARCHING')
        ->first();
```

How I can get all `PvpBattle` objects where the associated `player1_id` has +- 100 score difference from `$this->me->score`?

Comment: `->where(score, '>=', $this->me->score - 100)->where(score, '<=', $this->me->score + 100)`

Comment: `score` is in my `users` table, not in my `PvpBattle` object table

Comment: Then join with `users` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code

**WhereHas('users')** is the user relation between PvpBattle and user

```
$minScore = $this->me->score - 100;
$maxScore = $this->me->score + 100;
$pvp = PvpBattle::where('mode','=','SEARCHING')
                ->WhereHas('users', function ($query)  use ($minScore, $maxScore){

                $query->Where(function ($subQuery) use ($minScore, $maxScore){
                    $subQuery->orWhere('score', '<=', $maxScore)
                          ->orWhere('score', '>=', $minScore);
                });
            })
            ->first();
```

Comment: 5th line returns error of `->`, what's the right syntax for this query? It might work :)

Comment: 5th line in query or from top?

Comment: removed that semicolon before first()

Comment: The problem is in this line `->Where(function ($query) {` which is placed after a brackets `{` and ends up like `{->`

Comment: put use ($minScore, $maxScore) inside  ->Where(function ($query) use ($minScore, $maxScore) {

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)` ON LINE `->Where(function ($query) use ($minScore, $maxScore){`

Comment: forget to add $query->Where condition now you can check it

Answer (score 0):

First find the score of player one to    `$scoreA` or use `$this->me->score`

Then
    `$opp_list=PvpBattle::where('mode','=','SEARCHING')->Where(function($query)
    {
        $query->where('score', '>=', $scoreA -100)
              ->orwhere('score', '<=', $scoreA+100);
})
->get();`

This gets all the players in mode searching with condition score +-100. first() returns the first result from the table.

How are you going to handle two requests at the same time pointing to the same user?

User A should be not returned as a result.
Add `->where('user_id', '!=', $user_id)` to query

Answer (score 0):

Use a join with the `users` table to filter the result by the score of the related user.

```
$pvps = PvpBattle::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'pvpbattle.user_id')
    ->where('pvpbattle.mode','=','SEARCHING')
    ->where('users.score', '>=', $this->me->score - 100)
    ->where('users.score', '<=', $this->me->score + 100)
    ->get()
;
```